# submitting asp form by using JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

Firstly, some short explanations for the pages that we will be using here in the example.

`A.asp`

The page where user interacts with various controls, fills the info, and submits the form.

`B.asp`

The page that creates session variables and stores values as well as serves as an intermediate page where it passes value / redirects to C.asp.

`C.asp`

The page that does processing and displays results.

So in short, the flow is something like, A -> B -> C

Now, what I'd like to achieve is to put the results right on A.asp instead of seeing them on C.asp. I guess I should be able to do it with JQuery Ajax, perhaps simply by using `$("div#loadResults").load("B.asp")`.

But somehow I couldn't make it happen with above line of code. I think I must have missed something there. Can anyone kindly give suggestions or thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT:

It is actually a massive Form, so I don't think it'd be good idea to upload huge chunk of code directly to here.

EDIT2:

Another question is: which of the following should I be using, `Button.click()`, `Button.submit()` or `Form.submit()`?

Comment: @ Edit2: You should use 'button.click()' so you still have one action slot free. By the way, I think the event 'button.submit()' makes no sense.